# phpspreadsheet - PHP - How to add new data into an existing .xlsm file

Tags: php, excel, xlsm, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to take data from '.csv' files and put it into specific cells inside a '.xlsm' file. I'm doing this with PHP and the PHPSPREADSHEETS library.

So far I've gotten to a part where I can add data to an '.xlsx' file, but as soon as I try to add data to a '.xlsm' file, compatibility issues arise and the '.xlsm' file shows up empty.  Is this extension even supported at all? If it is, is there a way to 'update' an existing Excel sheet? So far it just deletes all the data and puts in the data I want, where I want it.

Or is there a different language to do this in? A way for people to upload their files and with a click on the button get the updated '.xlsm' file?